# WD USB HDD not recognized: Elements 10B8

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, thinkpad, usb-storage

Any idea what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Details:

- HDD: [WD Elements 2TB](http://www.amazon.de/Elements-Portable-externe-Festplatte-schwarz/dp/B00D0L5BH8/) (P/N: WDBU6Y0020BBK-05)
- When first connecting the device to my ThinkPad T420si ([4174-E37](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t420s/4174/e37)), a
  dialog appeared stating that Windows is attempting to install a driver.
  The driver installation, however, failed. According to Western Digital,
  there is no driver anyhow, and the HDD should work without driver.
- In the *Device Manager,* the drive is displayed with an exclamation mark as
  *Other devices / Elements 10B8*:

  [image: Screenshot of Device Manager]
- In *Disk Management*, it is not displayed:

  [image: Screenshot of Disk Managment]
- I tried all three USB ports on the machine, two USB 2.0, and one USB 3.0,
  all without success.
- Other USB HDDs work fine.
- When the HDD is connected, the status LED is shining, and the case vibrates,
  i.e. it appears to be running.
- An old ThinkPad T43 with Windows XP does detect the HDD.
- I called WD support. The support technician didn't know about this
  particular problem. He recommended that I reinstall the USB drivers of the
  machine, which I did. First, I uninstalled the driver for *Elements 10B8*,
  then uninstalled the drivers for the three USB controllers listed in
  *Device Manager:*

  [image: Screenshot showing USB controllers in Device Manager]

  After restarting the machine, I installed the [USB driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UCix.png) available
  from Lenovo, then connected the WD HDD to the USB 3.0 port. Again I got a
  message about a failed HDD driver installation, and now everything is like
  before.
- Properties according to [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html):

  [image: Screenshot of properties window in USBDeview]

Comment: You should follow the advice you have been already been given.  Update your question when you do.

Comment: @Ramhound Done. As expected, reinstalling the USB driver didn't change anything.

Comment: What driver is the HDD attempting to use? Have you tried setting it to a generic USB Mass Storage Device driver, or is it already loading (and failing) on that?

Comment: @smoooosher It doesn't find any driver, hence the error message. *Where do I find the generic USB Mass Storage device driver for Windows 7?*

Comment: @feklee try the driver at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\USBSTOR.SYS - might show up under the Driver wizard as brand "Compatible USB Storage Device"

Comment: After trying out various things, my system did not properly detect any USB mass storage devices. I solved that problem as explained in my answer to the post ["Windows 7 does not detect USB mass storage devices anymore"](http://superuser.com/questions/926407/windows-7-does-not-detect-usb-mass-storage-devices-anymore). Now also the WD HDD is detected, and that's why I flagged this question as duplicate.