# Windows 7 does not detect USB mass storage devices anymore

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, thinkpad, usb-storage

In an attempt to get a [WD USB HDD to work](https://superuser.com/questions/925171/wd-usb-hdd-not-recognized-elements-10b8) I followed a suggestion to uninstall all devices of type *Mass Storage* using [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html). Now, Windows 7 does not show any mass storage device, even the ones that worked previously. For example, a connected USB pen drive is listed in USBDeview as not connected:

[image: Screenshot of USBDeview]

In the *Device Manager* it appears with an exclamation mark:

[image: Screenshot of Device Manager]

It is not shown at all in *Disk Managment*.

I already tried reinstalling my [ThinkPad T420si's](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t420s/4174/e37) Intel chipset drivers, but to
no avail.

*How do I get USB mass storage to work again?*

Comment: System Restore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone [pointed](http://thinkpad-forum.de/threads/188380-USB-HDD-wird-unter-7-nicht-erkannt?p=1898707&viewfull=1#post1898707) me to a [post](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/86442-unable-install-any-usb-devices.html#post1014226) in sevenforums.com by [Difusal](http://www.sevenforums.com/members/difusal.html).
After following the steps in the post, I deleted the entry with the exclamation
mark in the *Device Manager*, then replugged the device. The mass storage driver
installed automatically, and the drive is now detected.

Steps, copied from the aforementioned forum post, reformatted and with typos
and spelling corrected:

1. Open *Windows Explorer*.
2. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore`.

   You will have a couple of folders and files.

   You will have `*.dat` files and another file named: `infcache.1`
3. Right click every file (don't touch the folders!) and choose properties.
4. Go to the *Security* tab.
5. Click *Edit*.
6. Choose your account and check the box: *Full Control* (see ss)
7. Click *OK.*
8. Repeat for every file.
9. Select all the files (`*.dat` and `infcache.1`).
10. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.
11. Click *OK.*
12. Now, go to `C:\Windows\System32\Driver Store\File Repository`.
13. Search folders containing `usbstor.inf`.
14. Open it (if you have more than one, choose the most recent).
15. Copy `usbstor.inf` and `usbstor.PNF`.
16. Paste those two files to `C:\Windows\inf`.
17. Reboot your PC and voilà! :b

Answer (score 1):

Find the hardware ID of the device by right clicking on the device selecting properties and navigating to Details then hardware ids in the drop-down menu.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRfah.png]

Take the top one and search it on Google preferably. See if you can find the corresponding device or if your lucky, the recommended driver for the device and download that from the support page of lenovo.

Comment: How do I help people then? I cant comment so I cant help before I post on my own questions enough?

Comment: [Why can people answer a question before being able to comment?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/9063)

Comment: Essentially what I have to do is post a full response instead of a request. So I cant do tiered support until I hit 50 but I can post simple fixes in the answers category. I edited my earlier post to show a full response, does that comply with your rules?

Comment: Yes. And they are not my rules. They are the community rules. I've inlined the image for you.

Comment: You are welcome. It won't take long to get 50 rep if you keep writing good questons and answers.

Comment: This is not helpful as mine is a general problem, not one specific to one mass storage device.

Comment: @DavidPostill as a stackexchange beginner you cant comment. The need of Karma to comment is a real thing that bugs me because you only are able to "Answer" when you are new on this page. And yes I know that this something i should talk about in Meta

Comment: @JonasDralle This has already been discussed on meta many many times. See [Why can people answer a question before being able to comment?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/9063) for just one example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an "WD Elements 2 TB" disc. The issue was that my USB Hub didn´t produce enough power. In the manual WD said I might need a special Y-Wire which isn´t included. But my notebook vendor (HP) said I need to use another USB port (one with a small flash beside the USB icon). This special USB port offered more power and using that USB port solved my issue.