# USB devices driver install issues on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, inf

I'm in need of some help.

a week ago a user wasn't able access the files on his new USB Sandisk Cruzer, the USB shows up in Device Manager but is unable to install the correct drivers either by selecting the "search online" or "Browse Manually".

initially I thought it was just an issue with just his USB but then realized that it was all newly connected USB devices.

steps I've taken so far (in order)

1) followed instructions on [Sandisk Website](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/205/~/sandisk-device-not-detected-by-windows-pc) to delete registry keys with the name VID_0781.
2) ran sfc /scannow - everything was fine.
3) tried a system restore but it won't complete successfully (this is a separate issue i'll have to deal with...).
4) replaced the .inf drivers as suggested in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/926407/windows-7-does-not-detect-usb-mass-storage-devices-anymor) post.

yesterday one of the check scanner stopped working only after replacing the .inf files did it start to work again.

after all these steps after trying to manually install the drivers this is the error I see "Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error trying to install it"

these are the devices currently connected to PC via USB that aren't having issues keyboard, mouse, 1 document scanners and 2 check scanners.

I don't want to have to do a clean install of the PC if i'm left with no other choice i'll be forced to do it.

Thank You for helping.

Comment: Do you have any more detailed errors (e.g. from eventviewer). Did you change anything recently about installation rights? (e.g. to get access to a folder which was owned by that pesky trusted installer uid?).

Comment: @Hennes what I'm I looking for under in event viewer? I haven't changed anything. (besides for adding full control over those .dat file in order to delete them)

Comment: I was hoping that there were some specific 'permission denied' message showing precise folders and files.

Comment: Try uninstalling all the usb root hub entries in device manager, then click the "scan for hardware changes" icon to reinstall the drivers

Comment: @Moab I've just tried that and rescanned it but now it doesn't install that either, restarted the PC still doesn't install not the drivers or the root hub, I'm in bad luck and need help...

Comment: Time for a clean install.

Comment: turns out there were a few viruses, until Thursday evening I only checked Anti-Virus program on PC which didn't detect anything, once I booted into Bit Defender I found few issues. once I restarted PC still the USB's weren't recognized but I tried again manually guiding it to C:\Windows\inf it found the driver but gave me a red warning that it isn't trusted and asking if I wan't to proceed anyways I clicked yes and it detects drivers and I'm able to use USB, I'm probably going to do a  clean install sometime. Thank You very much @Moab for your time assisting me.

Comment: Good that you solved it (and even better that you found the virusses). Please feel free to post your own answer and accept it. (These comments should disappear after some time. Answers will not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out there were a few viruses, at the time I only checked Symantec Endpoint Protection on PC which didn't detect anything, once I booted into Bit Defender I found few issues.
I restarted the PC and the USB's were still not being recognized but I tried again manually browsing to C:\Windows\inf and it found the driver but gave me a red warning that it isn't trusted and asking if I want to proceed anyways I clicked yes and it detected the drivers and now I'm able to use the USB's.